1 System, 2 Tasks, 2 NICs, 2 Networks: will it work?
I'm very new to networking, and have learned almost everything I know through working in the Unifi environment. (point is, I might sound smarter than I am.)
I'm about to pull the trigger on a second NIC for one of my systems, but need to understand how to implement my plan, or even if it's possible.
I'm using Windows 10 on an older system with a few cores and an integrated 1Gb NIC.
I'm connected through a Unifi Gateway with the networks set and ready.
I have a fairly large HDD installed to use as FileShare on Data network, VLAN 1, 192.168.0.0/24 with .0.1 as gateway. This network has internet access.
I will be setting up a system of 3 security cams through a Ubiquiti Tough Switch 8, POE. SecCam network is set at VLAN 50, 192.168.50.0/29. This network will not have a default gateway, nor will it have internet access.
My assumptions are:
I will need to set the integrated NIC to static on VLAN 1 and the discrete NIC static on VLAN 50.
Will Windows 10 be smart enough to understand what my goal is?
Are the software packages out there smart enough to understand?
What do I need to learn to be able to navigate this?
It sounds simple, but I know I'm looking at it from a VERY high level.
Any advice would be appreciated.

As long as the additional NICs are used for destinations that can be explicitly defined and don't overlap (i.e. all expressed in terms of routing table entries), this doesn't require any "smart enough" from the OS; it still falls under basic IP routing that probably every OS implements the same way.
(That is, the relevant concepts are routes and a routing table – which works mostly the same in Windows as it does in UniFi or other systems.)
You would start having difficulties if you had e.g. two default gateways (i.e. two routes for same destination) as then you would be getting into nonstandard, OS-specific behaviors. But in your case with a single IP subnet, just setting the IP address and subnet mask on the new NIC is what tells the OS where packets for 192.168.50.0/29 are supposed to go. The main NIC can remain DHCP.
Software packages mostly shouldn't care as long as it only involves "direct" communications to specific IP addresses (the OS automatically selects the route and the program doesn't need to do anything). Problems occur mostly when the program wants to send or receive broadcasts (automatic camera discovery), then it might need to be smart enough to try all interfaces or let you select a specific one – I've seen a few tools that only ever tried the NIC that was associated with the default route, but I'd kind of expect security camera software to be written with a separate network in mind.

I'd make the new subnet also a /24 for consistency if there's still enough address space available; same subnet size = less opportunity for typos when configuring netmasks.
With two separate NICs, Windows doesn't care about VLANs as it just gets untagged traffic on both. But if bandwidth is not an issue, you could set up both networks as 'tagged' VLANs on a single integrated NIC (which Windows can do now, using a piece of Hyper-V).
Similarly, if you only need direct communications (and not broadcast-based autodiscovery), you could let your UniFi gateway handle the routing; a PC in 192.168.0.0/24 can perfectly well talk to cameras in 192.168.50.0/29. The gateway's firewall rules could be used to enforce restrictions of who can access to the camera subnet.
